# how to implement full text search in database

Tags: database, database-design, full-text-search

I understand that full text indexing and search for a database can be enabled by a lot of pre-packaged products. However, just out of academical curiosity, I wonder how are those full text indexes actually implemented. I have tried to google for results with little answer. Please any feedback would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Full text searches are supported by quite a few database engines these days as a core feature.

As for implementation I think your best bet is to check out postgres [full text searches,](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/textsearch.html) as you can

- find a lot of material on how it is implemented
- actually change and play with the parsers (for example optimize for certain domain)

There are further details and concept explained on wikipedia:

- [full text indexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_index), and you can also check out
- [open source and free full text search engines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search#Free_and_open_source_software) as normally you will find supporting documentation explaining inner workings of those too (I have heard good things about [Lucene/Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/) from this list)

Answer (score 0):

Probably by creating dictionaries of "words" and maybe a bit of lexical analysis. (Note that fulltext searches whole words and not parts of words, so indexing may be constrained to that.)